# Django DateTimeField showing different time in shell and browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, orm

I just made a Coupon model in Django and displaying the valid_from and valid_till in the template.

The value show in django shell ORM is the actual time created, and count 20days from it till it expires. However the one in template keep showing the CURRENT time and counts 20days from the CURRENT time.

It's my first time trying something outside of tutorial and I don't know how to pinpoint a "fix", especially when django orm shell is showing the right time as I intended.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
import uuid


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            
        img= Image.open(self.image.path)
        
        if img.height> 300 or img.width> 300:
            output_size= (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)    

def twentydays_coupon():
    return timezone.now()+ timedelta(days=20)

class Coupon(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)        
    valid_from= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    valid_till= models.DateTimeField(default=twentydays_coupon)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Coupon'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from .models import Coupon

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! {username} is now able to login!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form= UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance= request.user)
        p_form= ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance= request.user.profile)
        
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form= UserUpdateForm(instance= request.user)
        p_form= ProfileUpdateForm(instance= request.user.profile)
            
    context= {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'Coupon': Coupon,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

profile.html

```
{% extends "info/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">Coupon valid from {{ Coupon.valid_from }}</p>
          <p class="text-secondary">Coupon valid till {{ Coupon.valid_till }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
                {{ u_form|crispy }}
                {{ p_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile, Coupon

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_coupon(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Coupon.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Are you saving the coupons once they are created ? @Kentypop

Comment: @Ram OH!!!!!!!! I created a coupon signals and everytime a user is registered it is created, but I think I didnt SAVE THEM!!!! I think you got it right!! THANKS sherlock!